# Java NullpointerException in the main class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

The problem:

After creating an array of FractionClass objects I try to give each Fraction a numerator and denominator ,by reading in a txtfile that looks like this:

```
11 12

7 24

2 3

5 6

7 9
...
```

The first number being the numerator and the second one being the denominator, to do this I use the Scanner class.
Under the readFractions-methode i placed comments where the NULLpointerexception is located.

**The mainfile:**

```
package labo2oef5;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Labo2Oef5 {

private static Breuk [] fractionArray;
private static int amountOfLines;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        lengteBestand(); // stel amountOfLines al in
        readFractions();
        System.out.println(fractionArray[4].getNumerator()+" / "+  fractionArray[4].getDenominator());`

    }

    public static void readFractions() throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner lezer = new Scanner(new File("breuken01.txt"));
        fractionArray = new Breuk[amountOfLines];
        for(int i=0; i<amountOfLines;i++){
            double numerator = (double) lezer.nextInt();
            double denominator = (double) lezer.nextInt();
            fractionArray[i].setNumerator(numerator); // HERE IT GOES WRONG, THE NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION IS HERE
            fractionArray[i].setDenominator(denominator);// THIS LINE SUFFERS AS WELL FROM THE NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION
            lezer.nextLine();
        }

    }

    public static int lengteBestand() throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner lezer = new Scanner(new File("breuken01.txt"));
        amountOfLines=0;
        while(lezer.hasNextLine()){
            amountOfLines++;
            lezer.nextLine();
        }
        return amountOfLines;
    }

}
```

**The Breuk(is dutch for Fraction) class:**

```
package labo2oef5;

public class Breuk {

    private double numerator, denominator;

    public Breuk() {
        numerator = 0;
        denominator = 1;
    }

    public Breuk(double numerator, double denominator) {
        this.numerator = numerator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String breuk = numerator + "/" + denominator;
        if (numerator == 0) {
            breuk = "0";
        }
        return breuk;
    }

    private static double grootsteGemeneDeler(double a, double b) {
        if (a < 0 || b < 0) {
            return grootsteGemeneDeler(Math.abs(a), Math.abs(b));
        }
        if (b == 0) {
            return a;
        }
        if (a < b) {
            return grootsteGemeneDeler(b, a);
        }
        if (a % b != 0) {
            return grootsteGemeneDeler(b, a % b);
        } else {
            return b;
        }
    }

    public String normaliseer() {

        double numerator2 = numerator / (grootsteGemeneDeler(numerator, denominator));
        double denominator2 = denominator / (grootsteGemeneDeler(numerator, denominator));
        return numerator2 + "/" + denominator2;
    }

    public double decimaleVorm() {
        double decim = (double) numerator / denominator;
        System.out.println(decim);
        return decim;
    }

    public boolean isGroterDan(Breuk br) {
        if (this.decimaleVorm() > br.decimaleVorm()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void vermeerderBreuk(Breuk br) {
        this.numerator = this.numerator * br.denominator + this.denominator * br.numerator;
        this.denominator = this.denominator * br.denominator;
    }

    public void produkt(Breuk br, Breuk breu) {
        numerator = br.numerator * breu.numerator;
        denominator = br.denominator * breu.denominator;
    }

    public void setNumerator(double numerator) {
        this.numerator = numerator;
    }

    public void setDenominator(double denominator) {
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }

    public double getNumerator() {
        return numerator;
    }

    public double getDenominator(){
        return denominator;
    }
}
```

Both answers are the right answer ,I just had to add this code underneath their answer as well:
            if (lezer.hasNextLine()) {
                lezer.nextLine();
            }

Comment: First of all, Sylwek and duffymo are right. You haven't initialized the array elements before accessing the objects / their setter methods. Moreover, it could be reasonable to check using hasNextInt() whether your source file has enough integer values: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fractionArray[i]` is null, so it throws `NullPointerException`. 
I think that you should do it like that:

```
fractionArray[i] = new Breuk();
fractionArray[i].setNumerator(numerator);
fractionArray[i].setDenominator(denominator);
```

Comment: Ah ,so the 
fractionArray = new Breuk[amountOfLines];
Only made room for 50 elements instead of filling them? So I had 50 empty 'boxes'...
I edited your code in and got this error now:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
 at labo2oef5.Labo2Oef5.readFractions(Labo2Oef5.java:32)
 at labo2oef5.Labo2Oef5.main(Labo2Oef5.java:18)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Yes, you have 50 empty "boxes". Try to check if there are still more elements in scanner using hasNextInt() method.

Comment: I edited this in under fractionArray[i] = new Breuk.... if (lezer.hasNextLine()) { lezer.nextLine(); } And it works as a charm now ,thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public static void readFractions() throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner lezer = new Scanner(new File("breuken01.txt"));
    fractionArray = new Breuk[amountOfLines];
    for(int i=0; i<amountOfLines;i++){
        double numerator = (double) lezer.nextInt();
        double denominator = (double) lezer.nextInt();
        fractionArray[i] = new Breuk(numerator, denominator);
        // Creating an array of references leaves them all null until you point them to something non-null by calling new
        lezer.nextLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried it and it gave this error back:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
 at labo2oef5.Labo2Oef5.readFractions(Labo2Oef5.java:31)
 at labo2oef5.Labo2Oef5.main(Labo2Oef5.java:18)
Java Result: 1

Comment: I edited this in under fractionArray[i] = new Breuk....
            if (lezer.hasNextLine()) {
                lezer.nextLine();
            }

And it works as a charm now ,thank you very much :)